# Need help with Zend form textbox validation

Tags: zend-framework, forms, zend-validate

Currently Im developing a website with Zend framework.

I need help with my suburb name validation

I need the validation to check if the input is in the following format

Suburb Name comma symbol space State abbreviations (State abbreviations consist exact three letters)

**Example: MANLY, NSW or SYDNEY, NSW or PALM BEACH, QLD**

Basically I need to validate in this format? So how can i do it in Zend framework? Do I need to write custom Zend form validation?

Thanks so much in advance :D

Comment: But what if a user will make a mistake when writing a state? Wouldn't it be better to put state as a select field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Zend_Validate_Regex for it.
Example:

```
$myValidator = new Zend_Validate_Regex('/^([a-zA-Z]+),\s(NSW|ACT|VIC|QLD|SA|WA|TAS|NT)$/');
$myValidator->setMessage('Your validation message goes here', Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH);
```

Then add validator to your field.

Comment: To ensure that the state value is exactly three letters, couldn't the pattern be: `'/^([a-zA-Z]+), ([a-zA-Z]{3})$/'`. But @Marcin right: the state field is better as a select control.

Comment: @David Weinraub It is true about regex. As to select field, I would rather add field description in this case - $field->setDescription('Enter suburb and state in the following format ...etc.');

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that all the [Australian states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_Australia#Australia_States_and_territories) use three-letter codes. If OP really doesn't want to use the select control (which I still think is best), then you could improve the regex as follows: `/^([a-zA-Z]+),\s*(NSW|ACT|VIC|QLD|SA|WA|TAS|NT)$/`, couldn't you?